# How to push from one NSViewcontroller to another NSViewcontroller in Mac OS X application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, pushviewcontroller

I tried below code but not working. I am new in Mac OS X App, please help me.

```
NSStoryboard *Story=[NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

TableViewVC *Controller=[Story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableViewVC"];

[self presentViewController:Controller animator:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is four way to present NSViewController

- AsPopover

  ```
  - (IBAction)presentAsPopover:(NSButton *)sender {
      NSViewController* vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
      [self presentViewController:vc
          asPopoverRelativeToRect:sender.frame
                           ofView:self.view
                    preferredEdge:NSMinYEdge
                         behavior:NSPopoverBehaviorTransient];

  }
  ```
- AsSheet

  ```
  - (IBAction)presentAsSheet:(NSButton *)sender {
      NSViewController* vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
      [self presentViewControllerAsSheet:vc];

  }
  ```
- AsModal

  ```
  - (IBAction)presentAsModal:(NSButton *)sender {
      NSViewController* vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
      [self presentViewControllerAsModalWindow:vc];

  }
  ```
- WithAnimator

  ```
  - (IBAction)presentWithAnimator:(NSButton *)sender {
      id animator = [[MyCustomAnimator alloc] init];
      NSViewController* vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
      [self presentViewController:vc animator:animator];

  }
  ```

Here is the Animator:

```
@interface MyCustomAnimator : NSObject <NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator>

@end

@implementation MyCustomAnimator
```

- to Show

  ```
  - (void)animatePresentationOfViewController:(NSViewController *)viewController fromViewController:(NSViewController *)fromViewController {

      NSViewController* bottomVC = fromViewController;
      NSViewController* topVC = viewController;

      // make sure the view has a CA layer for smooth animation
      topVC.view.wantsLayer = YES;

      // set redraw policy
      topVC.view.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay;

      // start out invisible
      topVC.view.alphaValue = 0;

      // add view of presented viewcontroller
      [bottomVC.view addSubview:topVC.view];


      // adjust size and colour
      CGRect frame = NSRectToCGRect(bottomVC.view.frame);
      frame = CGRectInset(frame, 40, 40);
      [topVC.view setFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(frame)];
      topVC.view.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor grayColor].CGColor;

      // Do some CoreAnimation stuff to present view
      [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
          context.duration = 0.5;
          topVC.view.animator.alphaValue = 0.8;
      } completionHandler:nil];

  }
  ```
- to Hide

  ```
  - (void)animateDismissalOfViewController:(NSViewController *)viewController fromViewController:(NSViewController *)fromViewController {

      //NSViewController* bottomVC = fromViewController;
      NSViewController* topVC = viewController;

      // make sure the view has a CA layer for smooth animation
      topVC.view.wantsLayer = YES;

      // set redraw policy
      topVC.view.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay;

      // Do some CoreAnimation stuff to present view
      [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
          context.duration = 0.5;
          topVC.view.animator.alphaValue = 0;
      } completionHandler:^{
          [topVC.view removeFromSuperview];
      }];

  }

  @end
  ```

### Keep in mind

To control the behavior of NSViewController,

It's easy to control NSViewController with its `xib` file existed.

A little complex to do it without `xib` file, or set in `storyboard`

Answer (score -1):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let myVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TableViewVC")
self.presentViewController(myVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You should also change your storyboard id like this: [image]

"TableViewVC" put this as storyboard id

Comment: this is code work for iOS app but I  a want Mac OS X application.